# MATLAB concatenate combination variable length string and vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, append

Many near-solutions are online, but nothing exact...

I am building a data matrix vector-by-vector:

```
OutputMatrix(NextSubject,:)=[OutputVector]
```

I need to lead each row with the name of the data being processed in that loop. The name has the form:

```
12345.dat
```

So if `OutputVector=[1 2 3 4]` the output should look like:

```
12345.dat 1 2 3 4
```

I have tried dozens of solutions, but a few examples:

```
{char(Filename(i).name) OutputVector}
{strcat((Filename(i).name) OutputVector)}
[Filname(i).name OutputVector]
```

Any help? Please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a string and a vector in a matrix.  However, you can do that in a cell. 
So you might consider doing:

```
   OutputCell(NextSubject,:) = { Filename(i).name  OutputVector };
```

The curly braces denote that you are storing the object as a cell. 
Often though it is better to store strings and number separately. Something like:

```
   OutputMatrix = [];
   OutputFile = {};

   ...

   OutputMatrix(NextSubject,:) = OutputVector; 
   OutputFile{NextSubject} = Filename(i).name;
```

Then if you access or select rows from output matrix, use the same index for the cell array:

```
   foo(OutputMatrix(index,:), OutputFile(index))
```